# Context.Request.Files is empty when uploading bigger files

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

AjaxHandler.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        int filesCount = context.Request.Files.Count; // is empty !!!
}
```

I'm using Ajax File Uploader called "RealUploader" to upload images, audio and video to Server side..

The strange thing was when sending files like images with small size all work done and correctly, but when i tried to upload bigger files like videos then
context.Request.Files was empty, i don't know Why?

Client Side Code

```
var uploader = new RealUploader("#targetElement", {
            accept: "video/*",
            allowedExtensions: ['mp4'],
            language: 'ar_AR',
            chunkSize: 104857600,
            maxFiles: 3,
            maxFileSize: 104857600,
            url: 'AjaxHandler.ashx',
....
....
});
```

WebConfig File// to ensure accepting big files with 100MB

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="3600" />
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"  />
      </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx), `maxRequestLength` is:

> The maximum request size in kilobytes. The default size is 4096 KB (4
>   MB).

If you have a value of 10240 then you have specified the limit as 10MB rather than 100MB. You should increase that number to 102400.

Comment: Woow! I have not noticed this trivial error though I have tried to be very attentive to it, thank you for your answer